# Access Python Dictionary elements containing dot in name

Tags: python-2.7

I have to read elements of of the following python dictionary:

```
dict = {'crawler.cmd': 'OS Path for CMD',
's3.failureBucket': 'Failure Bucket Name',
's3.landingBucket': 'Landing Bucket Name',
's3.rawBucket': 'Raw Bucket Name',
'src.name': 'StreamNameUpd'}
```

As the element name contains dots so, how would I access element with dot in name?

Comment: Accessing a dict element requires the  `[]` operator. May it be the case you are confusing it with Javascript?

Comment: @Umar you asked a question. I posted an answer. Did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

Given your dictionary:

```
my_dictionary = {'crawler.cmd': 'OS Path for CMD',
's3.failureBucket': 'Failure Bucket Name',
's3.landingBucket': 'Landing Bucket Name',
's3.rawBucket': 'Raw Bucket Name',
'src.name': 'StreamNameUpd'}
```

You can access any element just by putting its correspondant key in the square brackets like the following:

```
my_dictionary['crawler.cmd']
```

Output:

```
'OS Path for CMD'
```

Comment: Just a quick side-note that the variable name should _not_ be `dict`, since that is a built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get this:

`my_dictionary.get('crawler.cmd')`

With get() function you can also define a default value in case the key not in dict:

`my_dictionary.get('crawler.cmd', "my_value")`

Output:

> 'OS Path for CMD'